# How to solve simple differential equation (biology)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, applications, biology

First of all, I am a biologist and I am not really knowledgeable in mathematics. Thus, I apologize if what I am asking is naive or not fully explained.

I am trying to solve analytically a differential equation for the growth of a pile ($S$). The differential equation should be as follows:

$\frac{dS}{dt} = (k×J) - S(t)×L ×(k×J)$

where:

$S =$ size of the structure

$J =$ constant

$L =$ changing with S

Flow = constant = $k$

The equation can thus be simplified to:

$\frac{dS}{dt} = N - S(t) × L × N$

where $N = (k × J)$

Is there an analytical solution to this equation? If so, how can I achieve it? I would like to learn a bit about the process but not being in the field makes finding resources a little harder.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What do you mean by L is changing with S? in what way?

Comment: To be more specific: J is a probability of joining, while Flow is the number of agents moving into the system. L is a probability of leaving. We know that L is influenced by S, so that it decreases as S grows. 
This leads to N meaning the number of agents joining the system, and S*L*N being the number of agents leaving the system.

Comment: If $L$ is changing with $S$, we can't solve the DE unless it is specified how exactly $L$ depends upon $S$.

Comment: Do I need to create an additional DE for doing that? 
How would it be solved if L was a constant? I have a survival model estimate but it includes other variables. It is this model that indicates that L is changing with S. I may be able to use L as a constant that gets the second part of the equation smaller and smaller over time.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{dS(t)}{dt} = N - S(t) \, L \, N$$

If $L$ does not depend on time, then
$$S(t)=\frac{S(0) L-1 }{L}e^{-L N t}+\frac1 L$$

**Detailed steps**

First, about notations : $a b$ stands for $a\times b$.

We shall write the equation as
$$\frac{dS(t)}{dt} + S(t) \, L \, N=N\tag 1$$ Consider first the corresponding *homogeneous equation*
$$\frac{dS(t)}{dt} + S(t) \, L \, N=0$$ what rewrite as
$$\frac {dS(t) }{S(t)}=-L\, N \,dt$$ Integrate both sides
$$\log(S(t))=-L\, N \,t+c_1\implies S(t)=\exp\left(-L\, N \,t+c_1 \right)=\exp\left(-L\, N \,t\right)\exp(c_1)$$
$$S(t)=c_2 \exp\left(-L\, N \,t\right)$$ If the rhs in $(1)$ had been $0$, the problem would have been over and $c_2=S(0)$. But this is not the case; so, to take it into account, we consider that $c_2$ is a function of $t$. For clarity, let me write $c_2=C(t)$ (this is called *variation of parameters*). So
$$S(t)=C(t)\exp\left(-L\, N \,t\right)\implies \tag 2$$ $$\frac{dS(t)}{dt}=\frac{dC(t)}{dt}\exp\left(-L\, N \,t\right)-C(t)\,L\,N\,\exp\left(-L\, N \,t\right)$$ Plug in $(1)$ and simplify to obtain
$$\frac{dC(t)}{dt}=N e^{L N t}\implies C(t)=\frac{e^{L N t}}{L}+c_3$$ Back to $(2)$, we then have
$$S(t)=\Big[\frac{e^{L N t}}{L}+c_3 \Big]\exp\left(-L\, N \,t\right)$$ Expand and simplify
$$S(t)=c_3 e^{-L N t}+\frac{1}{L}$$ Apply the condition at $t=0$
$$S(0)=c_3+\frac{1}{L} \implies c_3=S(0)-\frac{1}{L}\implies S(t)=(S(0)-\frac{1}{L})e^{-L N t}+\frac{1}{L}$$ which was the answer.

Comment: Thanks! Can you give me some more info on the process? Also, what it Nt? it is just N*t?